# In iOS, How to set UITableViewCell margin while using the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set the margin of the cell, it can't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y66NR.png)

Then I override the 'get' and 'set' of the frame of the cell, and it works but it results in a bug: after the cell is swiped left or right, the cell can't return to the right place immediately, it has a time lag, then the cell restore to the right place.

```
override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
           return super.frame
        }
        set {
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += 10
            frame.origin.y += 10
            frame.size.width -= 20
            frame.size.height -= 10
            print("set:\(String(describing: titleLable?.text))")
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

bug:

[the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EWmY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4t3A.png)

So I wonder if there is some way to set the margin for the UITableView cell.

Comment: Trying to configure the frame is asking for trouble. You should place all your content in the cell’s `contentView` and use auto layout with constraints to the content view’s layout margin guide. You should not try and set frames manually.

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
        // write your code
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    
    
    let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: tableView.rowHeight))
    bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    bgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
// Create Your Background view for swipe action with a margin of 20 points
    let marginView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 60, height: tableView.rowHeight))
    marginView.addSubview(bgView)

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")
    deleteAction.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20) // add right margin to image
    deleteAction.title = nil
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete-background")!) // set pattern image as background
    
    // Return swipe action configuration with custom view
    let swipeconfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    swipeconfiguration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    swipeconfiguration.showsPreview = false
    swipeconfiguration.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    swipeconfiguration.expansionStyle = .destructive
    swipeconfiguration.actionBackgroundView = marginView
    
    return swipeconfiguration
}
```